# Border Pictures in Html

Tags: html, css

Below picture is the part of my website which I need to display some data in each boxes.

I imagined each box as div, but I could not figure out how to make stitchy borders. I don't want to use the whole picture in the web site as it would be awkward.

What would be the best way of converting this pic into HTML?

[image: Divs]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an image as a border with CSS3 by using `border-image`.

Here's an example, assuming that you have the cross saved as a single image*:

```
.crossBorder {
    border-width: 30px;
    -webkit-border-image:url(cross.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    -moz-border-image:url(cross.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    border-image:url(cross.png) 30 repeat stretch;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

*the single image would look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oqdl.png)

Comment: thanks for this Matt. what about the shadow on my original pic?

Answer (score 1):

make a seemless tile from the border shown, like this[image]

then give the background as below

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jBhPb/4/)
html

`<div class="div"></div`>

css

```
.div {

    background: url(http://s18.postimg.org/563hmngqd/vzcp_X.jpg),
                url(http://s18.postimg.org/563hmngqd/vzcp_X.jpg),
                url(http://s18.postimg.org/563hmngqd/vzcp_X.jpg),
                url(http://s18.postimg.org/563hmngqd/vzcp_X.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y,repeat-y,repeat-x,repeat-x;                 
    background-position: 0,right top,0 0,0 bottom;
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px;

}
```

you will get this [image]

for shadow effect,

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 5px #888;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. What about the shadow on the original picture(See above). I think I need to have different borders for each side?

Comment: shadow effect added to the answer.